# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in python3 http Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, http

when i run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy_http import http


def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)


def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        print(packet)


sniff("eth0")
```

i got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "packet_sniffer.py", line 16, in <module>
    sniff("eth0")   File "packet_sniffer.py", line 8, in sniff
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 886, in sniff
    r = prn(p)   File "packet_sniffer.py", line 13, in process_sniffed_packet
    print(packet)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 438, in
__str__
    return str(self.build())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 556, in build
    p = self.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in do_build
    pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in do_build_payload
    return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in do_build
    pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in do_build_payload
    return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in do_build
    pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in do_build_payload
    return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 541, in do_build
    pay = self.do_build_payload()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 528, in do_build_payload
    return self.payload.do_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 538, in do_build
    pkt = self.self_build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 179, in self_build
    return _self_build(self, field_pos_list)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 101, in _self_build
    val = _get_field_value(obj, f.name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 74, in _get_field_value
    headers = _parse_headers(val)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py", line 18, in _parse_headers
    headers = s.split("\r\n") TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

what should i do?

Comment: `sniff(b"eth0")`?

Comment: What version of scapy is installed?  According to https://scapy.net/download/, 2.4.2 supports Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this problem by using `python2` instead of `python3`. If you don't want to change your python version then you'd need to make some changes to `scapy-http`'s library codes. From your traceback I can see that file is located at: `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scapy_http/http.py`. Now open that file with any text editor.

Change *line 18* from:

```py
headers = s.split("\r\n")
```

to:

```py
try:
    headers = s.split("\r\n")
except TypeError as err:
    headers = s.split(b"\r\n")
```

Then change *line 109* from:

```py
p = f.addfield(obj, p, val + separator)
```

to:

```py
try:
    p = f.addfield(obj, p, val + separator)
except TypeError as err:
    p = f.addfield(obj, p, str(val) + str(separator))
```

Comment: You're not supposed to mess with the installation files, especially when not knowing the full implications.

Comment: sorry but a have just 16 line as i mention! i don't wanna change the module's code itself

Answer (score 0):

You're using `scapy_http` in addition to `scapy`.
`scapy_http` hasn't been update in a while, and has poor compatibility with Python 3+

Feel free to have a look at https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/1925 : it's not merged in Scapy yet (should be sometimes soon I guess) but it's an updated & improved port of `scapy_http`, made for the latest `scapy` version